# Reverse for 'allproduct' not found. 'allproduct' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name='shop'
urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.allproduct,name='allproductcat'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/',views.allproduct,name='product_by_catagory')

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from . models import catagory,product

# Create your views here.
def allproduct(request,c_slug=None):
    c_page=None
    products=None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page=get_object_or_404(catagory,slug=c_slug)
        products=product.objects.all().filter(catagory=c_page,available=True)
    else:
        products=product.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    return render(request,'catagory.html',{'catagory':c_page,'products':products})
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.urls import reverse


class catagory(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='catagory',blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('name',)
        verbose_name='catagory'
        verbose_name_plural='catagories'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_by_catagory',args=(self.slug,))

class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    stock=models.IntegerField()
    available=models.BooleanField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    catagory=models.ForeignKey(catagory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

catagory. html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block metadiscription %}
{% if catagory %}
{{catagory.discription}}
{% else %}
welcome
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
{% if catagory %}
{{catagory.name}}--ABC store
{% else %}
see our new collection
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if catagory %}
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'shop:allproduct' %}">OUR PRODUCT COLLECTION</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
<div>
    {% if catagory %}
    <img src="{{catagory.img.url}}" alt="{{catagory.name}}">
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <h1>
        {{catagory.name}}
    </h1>
    <p>
        {{catagory.discription}}
    </p>

</div>
{% else %}
<div>
    <img src="{% static 'img/banner.png' %}">
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <h1>OUR PRODUCT COLLECTION</h1>
    <p>INDIA IS MY COUNTRY I LOVE MY COUNTRY</p>
</div>
{% endif %}

<div>
    <div>
        {% for product in products %}
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="" ><img src="{{product.img.url}}"alt="image not found"></a>
                <div>
                    <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

context_processors.py

```
from . models import catagory

def menu_link(request):
    link=catagory.objects.all()
    return dict(links=link)
```

i can't load the catagory page using the slug address,that is dress, when i enter that it is showing there is no revrse for allproducts, and when i open the website there is no image in image position.as i have uploaded the image file in the admin pannel

Answer (score 0):

The `name=…` of your path is `allproductcat`, not <s>`allproduct`</s>, you thus should implement a link with:

```
<a href="{% url 'shop:allproductcat' %}">OUR PRODUCT COLLECTION</a>
```

Comment: thank you. but i can see my image in the respective position. as i have uploaded it in the adminpannel

Comment: @aswin: with `.image.url`, not `.img.url` The name of your field is `image`, not `img`.